# Can't write to location initialized with malloc

Tags: c++, malloc

I was trying to test if part of my program was working, but when running the following code,

```
Car *carList;
carList = (Car*) malloc (length * sizeof(Car));
carList[0].setMake("a");
carList[0].setModel("b");
carList[0].setYear("c");
carList[0].setColor("d");
carList[0].printCar();
```

The program encounters a problem within the first function call, setMake. Here is my car class:

```
class Car {
    private:
        string cmake;
        string cmodel;
        string cyear;
        string ccolor;

    public:
        Car(){};
        Car(string *cmake, string *cmodel, string cyear, string *ccolor);
        void printCar(){
            cout << "Make: " << cmake << endl;
            cout << "Model: " << cmodel << endl;
            cout << "Year: " << cyear << endl;
            cout << "Color: " << ccolor << endl << endl;
            return;
        };
        string getMake(){return cmake;};
        string getModel(){return cmodel;};
        string getYear(){return cyear;};
        string getColor(){return ccolor;};

        void setMake(string a){cmake = a;};
        void setModel(string a){cmodel = a;};
        void setYear(string a){cyear = a;};
        void setColor(string a){ccolor = a;};
};
```

When it tries to execute the function setMake, I get a error that says

```
No source available for "libstdc++-6!_ZN9__gnu_cxx9free_list8_M_clearEv()     at 0x6fc59021"
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `malloc()` doesn't initialize your class `Car` correctly, use `new` instead.

Comment: You could use [`placement new`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) after the `malloc` to ensure the constructor is called. Then you'd have to call the destructor explicitly as well. Its better to avoid `placement new` unless you know what you're doing and really need to use it.

Comment: I can understand changing the colour of an existing car, but changing the make, model and year doesn't make much sense. "You know my 1998 Toyota Corolla? I had the garage rebuild it to a 1967 Ford Mustang."

Comment: @molbdnilo This is probably to support parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use `new` instead of `malloc` because C++ objects must be initialized with constructor call.

In this particular situation the error is due to unconstructed `string` objects.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` just allocates memory, it doesn't initialize C++ objects. It looks like you want a dynamically-sized collection of `Car`s, so `std::vector<Car>` would work much better for you:

```
std::vector<Car> carList (length);
carList[0].setMake("a"); //assuming length>0
carList[0].setModel("b");
carList[0].setYear("c");
carList[0].setColor("d");
carList[0].printCar();
```

This will create a `length` sized `std::vector` default-initialized `Car`s, then set the requested properties on the first object in the vector and print it.